# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Installation

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, visual-c#-express-2010

I use VisualStudio 2010 and olso have Visual C# 2010 Express installed on my computer.

And I have to install Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2, but during the instillation warning appears  --

> "A previous release of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 is installed on
>   this computer. Upgrade Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 to the SP1... "

When I tried to upgrade VS 2008 it said "There is no VS 2008 on your computer". =)

How can I solve this problem with intent using VS 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**At Your Own Risk** 
I think you need make some changes in the registry  please follow these steps 

1. Type regedit in run

2. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv

3. Find the VS or vs folder rename it to vs_1

Hopefully it will work. This what i did once.

Comment: And always remember: hacking the registry is the moral equivalent of "Nurse?  Chainsaw!" ;)

Comment: I would appreciate if you explain what I've just done with registry or what was the problem in )

Answer (score 0):

The version numbers are different, but this appears to be your scenario:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956139

My initial advice would be "treat your MSSQL 2008 install as a fresh install".  I would still suggest "Try the 'fresh install', and see how far you get."

Microsoft's advice, however, is "uninstall the version that came with MSVS first".

Do whatever you think is best.

I'd definitely take a backup first ;)

Comment: Those suggestions work with VS 2008, I'm using VS 2010 SP1. Is it possible they are not compatible?